# How do you know if a Socket.Send() has worked?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Quite a simple question - I've been having some TCP packets go missing (they aren't received by the remote socket), so I'm considering resending any packets that don't get received.

However I need to know when send doesn't work in order to do this! I know Send() returns an integer containing the 'The number of bytes sent to the Socket', but even when the other computer receives nothing, this is always the length of the entire buffer, indicating that everything was (theoretically) sent. I also know there's a Socket.Connected property, but that is false even when that data is received, and sometimes true even when it isn't, so that doesn't help either.

So how do I know if Send() has worked?

Comment: Are you absolutely convinced that the problem is on the sending side rather than the receiving side? What's the evidence for that? Have you use Wireshark or something similar to view the traffic?

Comment: TCP is leaky.. You should read this [leakyabstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/leakyabstractions.html)

Comment: @Sriram how is that relevant? That article does not say: _"TCP drops arbitrary packets"_, which you seem to imply.

Comment: If you are working with C# why are you working with the socket's class and not one of the higher level abstractions built in to the .NET framework like `TcpClient`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have experienced it. When I send "1", "2", "3" as seperate messages in `socket.Send` sometimes receiver received "1" "3" "3" "3". You may not believe but not a joke. I mean it.

Comment: @Sririam you really can blame your code there, as [TCP provides reliable, ordered, error-checked delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

Comment: @CodeCaster I know you won't believe. but.. You'll do once when it happens to you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel if that would occur, this website would alsoould occur, this website would also show repeating data out of nowhere.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Again am saying it happened to me. I cross checked every code logged properly. I send "1", "2", "3" and what received is "1" "3" "3" "3". Not always but sometimes. If you check the article which I linked you'll come to know there might me something went wrong when TCP tries to resend the packets and it send wrong one. Note: this may be problem with network or ISP or whatever. but tcp was the conveyer, It leaked there. If it happens to you in future that time you'll remember me :)

Comment: @Sriram what you are explaining really is **impossible** with TCP. The culprit **must** have been your code, or perhaps a faulty network driver or card if it happened on one machine only. The [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/leakyabstractions.html) you linked do does **not** say TCP randomly drops or repeats packets, in any way.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that TCP is oriented around a *stream* - there's no guarantee that 3 calls to `Send` at one end will be matched by 3 calls to `Receive` at the other end - people frequently expect TCP to be *message* based, which it definitely isn't. If you need *messaging*, you have to implement that on top of the stream.

Comment: @CodeCaster **May be** when TCP tries to send the lost packet again something would have gone wrong. and not on only one machine. We checked with servers in datacentre and also with local dev server also. I agree with you am not 100% sure that problem is with tcp, and problem may be with **network**.. Can't believe it happened. and we keep it there we don't agree to each other. This is purely my assumption only..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I'm still gonna bet on your code:(

Comment: Duplicated packets caused by ACKs getting lost is handled by TCP.

Comment: @MartinJames Am still gonna decline it.. :)

Comment: @Sriram read the [TCP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) to learn why what you are claiming is impossible: _"The TCP must recover from data that is damaged, lost, duplicated, or delivered out of order by the internet communication system. This is achieved by assigning a sequence number to each octet transmitted, and requiring a positive acknowledgment (ACK) from the receiving TCP. At the receiver, the sequence numbers are used to correctly order segments that may be received out of order and to eliminate duplicates. "_.

Answer (score 1):

`Send()` simply places the data in a buffer for the network adapter to process. When `Send()` returns, you have no guarantee that a single byte has "left" your computer, even when the socket is in blocking mode.

TCP ensures though that within a connection all data is received in the order it was sent. It never "forgets" a packet in the middle of a conversation, and automatically retransmits data when needed.

To determine whether retransmission is required, the protocol sends acknowledgement messages, but:

- you can't access them from the `Socket` class
- hosts may postpone sending this ACK message

The easiest way to ensure your message has arrived is to let the other party respond to them yourself. If you don't receive a response within a reasonable amount of time, you could treat that connection as broken.

About the whole discussion between Sriram Sakthivel and "the others" - I've had similar problems of receiving duplicate messages and missing others, but *in my personal case* this was caused by:

- using `BeginReceive()` (the async receive method),
- reusing the same buffer on each `BeginReceive()` call, and
- calling `BeginReceive()` before processing that buffer, causing the buffer to be filled with new data before having read the old message.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way of doing this is to check if the `bufferedAmount` is zero after you've sent a message. The trick is, you'll have to let your application know you are in fact sending a message.